# How to configure Multiple reporters in Cypress Docker container?

Tags: docker, junit, cypress, mochawesome

Cypress provides a manual for installing and configuring multiple reporters: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/reporters#Merging-reports-across-spec-files

My goal is to make it work in a Docker container and provide the results to the host machine. What was done for this aim:

1. Dockerfile:

   ```
   FROM cypress/base:14.17.0
   RUN mkdir /cypress-docker
   WORKDIR /cypress-docker
   COPY . /cypress-docker
   RUN npm install --save-dev cypress
   RUN $(npm bin)/cypress verify
   RUN ["npm", "run", "cypress:e2e"]
   ```
2. reporter-config.json:

   ```json
   {
       "reporterEnabled": "mocha-junit-reporter, mochawesome",
       "mochaJunitReporterReporterOptions": {
         "mochaFile": "cypress/results/junit/results-[hash].xml"
       },
       "reporterOptions": {
           "reportDir": "cypress/results/mochawesome",
           "overwrite": false,
           "html": false,
           "json": true
       }
   }
   ```
3. docker-compose.yml:

   ```yaml
   version: '3.7'
   services:
     cypress_test:
       image: cypress_compose
       build:
         context: .
         dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
       volumes:
         - ./dockerReports:/cypress-docker/cypress/results
         - ./dockerReports:/cypress-docker/mochawesome-report
   ```
4. package.json:

   ```json
   {
     "name": "cypress-docker",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "",
     "main": "index.js",
     "scripts": {
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
       "delete:reports": "rimraf cypress/results && mkdirp cypress/results",
       "prereport": "npm run delete:reports",
       "mochawesome:merge": "npx mochawesome-merge \"cypress/results/mochawesome/*.json\" > mochawesome.json && npx marge mochawesome.json",
       "junit:merge": "npx junit-merge -d cypress/results/junit -o cypress/results/junit/result.xml",
       "cypress:run": "npm run prereport && npx cypress run",
       "cypress:e2e": "npm run cypress:run && npm run junit:merge && npm run mochawesome:merge"
     },
     "author": "",
     "license": "ISC",
     "devDependencies": {
       "cypress": "^8.2.0",
       "cypress-multi-reporters": "^1.5.0",
       "junit-merge": "^2.0.0",
       "mocha": "^7.8.1",
       "mocha-junit-reporter": "^2.0.0",
       "mochawesome": "^6.2.2",
       "mochawesome-merge": "^4.2.0",
       "mochawesome-report-generator": "^5.2.0"
     }
   }
   ```

So, I hope to have a directory `dockerReports` containing merged JUnit and Mochawesome reports on the host machine after running `docker-compose up` command. And this directory does appear but it is empty. What is the reason?